# How to put row level validation in IgnitedDatatables using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

I am using [IgnitedDatatables plugin](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables) on my Codeigniter project where I am listing records of area names. I want to put row level validations so that if the the area name is e.g. Area A, then I show it in red color, if Area name is B then I show it in green color etc. This is just a basic example to explain what I am trying to achieve. Actual purpose is different. I have listed all the areas with Delete button. I want to check if any Area is used then I have to restrict deletion on it.

I already tried to find solution for this and found that native php library for IgniterDatatables allow to use Callback functions for same purpose. But that is not supported for Codeigniter.

Any solutions for this? Below is part of my code.

```
public function get_list(){
    $this->load->library('datatables');

    $this->datatables->select('Area_id, Area_name, Pin, City');
    $this->datatables->from('areamaster');

    $buttons ='<a href="areamaster/delete/$1" class="icon-remove" title="Delete" onclick="javascript:return confirm_delete();"></a>';

    $this->datatables->add_column('actions', $buttons, 'Area_id');

    echo $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

Comment: you may add javascript/ajax on click event to the button return false in case of used ..

Comment: no actually I don't want the buttons to be visible while they are used